# Why am I getting this error: Can not execute 'setup.py' since setuptools is not available in the build environment

Tags: python, file, email, setuptools, setup.py

I tried to run

`pip install email`

but I got the following error:

```
error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [1 lines of output]
      ERROR: Can not execute `setup.py` since setuptools is not available in the build environment.
      [end of output]
```

I tried uninstalling setuptools and reinstalling it. But, I don't know where it's supposed to be located. I do have ez_setup.py, but I don't think it's in the right location anyway.
Also, when I search for setuptools, it says that it cannot be found, but when I try to install it, the "requirement is already filled."
What could be causing this error, and what is the proper organization of my files in regard to the setuptools folder? Can anybody walk me through installing setuptools and making sure that my program can use it? Or, is there another way to install email? Thanks!

EDIT:
After I was messing with the files on my computer, requests somehow stopped functioning without the email package. I just decided to cut the library out of my program, which went well. Anyway, the issue just disappeared, and I am no longer going to mess with it.... Sorry if that is not helpful to anybody who was looking for a solution to a similar problem. My only advice would be to find a different package to use. Thanks to everybody in the comments who looked into this issue

Comment: From pypi.org it looks like [the `email` package](https://pypi.org/project/email) has been unmaintained for a long time, with the last update being in 2007. Are you sure this is the package you want?

Comment: Note that there is an email  package in the standard library.